# Закрасить текст, слово, букву

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток.

WPF Разрабатываю караоке плеер. Основную часть сделал. Получаю текст и музыку всё проигрываю всё хорошо) Встала задача теперь все это дело красиво вывести, как в настоящем караоке. что бы две строчки и текст закрашивать постепенно по тайм коду.

Так вот и вопрос как сделать красиво закрасить текст. Что для этого можно использовать?
Подскажите, направьте. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: использовать градиентую заливку, ну и анимировать ее.

Comment: А как это сделать не подскажите? или примерчик где какой есть?

Comment: О, а вот вам уже и ответили.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот вам решение с контурами букв и побуквенной постепенной заливкой.

Идея решения одолжена из комментария @S.Kost и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816(v=vs.110).aspx).

Для начала определим наш XAML.

Определяем невидимый `TextBlock` с текстом. Мы стащим из него свойства, и отрендерим текст самостоятельно. Почему нельзя было использовать видимый `TextBlock`? Дело в том, что он не умеет отрисовывать границу глифов, а мы хотим в начале, чтобы буквы были «пустыми».

Под ним в том же `Grid`'е кладём `Path`, который и будет содержать наш текст. У него есть `Stroke`, задающий границу, установим его цвет в чётный и толщину в пол-пикселя.

Затем, в заполнении кладётся наша градиентная заливка. Кладём 2 контрольных точки, которые будут пробегаться по каждой букве. Слева от первой точки будет чёрная, справа — белая заливка. Между точками — переход.

Затем, анимация. Мы анимируем продвижение контрольных точек вдоль букв. Откуда и докуда происходит анимация, устанавливается в code-behind.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Name="Source" Text="А-а, в Африке реки вот такой ширины"
               FontSize="24" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Path Name="Target" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5">
        <Path.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" x:Name="TargetFrom"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" x:Name="TargetTo" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
        <Path.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.25"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="TargetFrom"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.25"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="TargetTo"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Path.Resources>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

С XAML'ом покончено, теперь code-behind.

Для начала, нам нужна функция, которая вытащит из текста его геометрию, и измерит ширины всех букв. Заодно пропустим пробелы, их анимировать не стоит.

Для измерения геометрии текста воспользуемся удобным классом [`FormattedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
double extent;              // общая ширина текста
List<Rect> boundingBoxes;   // прямоугольники с каждым символом

void Create() // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816(v=vs.110).aspx
{
    TextBlock tb = Source;
    var text = tb.Text;
    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
        text,
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(
            tb.FontFamily,
            tb.FontStyle,
            tb.FontWeight,
            tb.FontStretch),
        tb.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black // конкретная кисть нам не важна, мы используем только геометрию
        );

    // стащили геометрию у текста...
    var geo = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point());
    // ...и отдали её Path'у
    Target.Data = geo;

    var bb = formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point());
    extent = bb.Bounds.Width; // общая ширина

    boundingBoxes =  // побуквенная ширина и позиции
        Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length)
                  .Where(k => !char.IsWhiteSpace(text[k]))
                  .Select(k => formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point(), k, 1)
                                            .Bounds)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Ну и нам нужна функция, запускающая в цикле для каждой буквы анимацию. Это совсем просто:

```
async void Play()
{
    var storyboard = (Storyboard)Target.Resources["AnimationStoryboard"];
    var fromAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)storyboard.Children[0];
    var toAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)storyboard.Children[1];

    foreach (var b in boundingBoxes)
    {
        await Task.Delay(250); // перерыв между буквами
        fromAnimation.From = b.Left / extent;
        fromAnimation.To = b.Right / extent;
        toAnimation.From = b.Left / extent;
        toAnimation.To = b.Right / extent;
        storyboard.Begin();
        await Task.Delay(250); // дождёмся конца анимации
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: А-а, в Африке реки вот такой ширины!]

Comment: Огромное, огромное спасибо.!!!!))

Comment: @N1VaL: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Comment: @VladD подскажите, пожалуйста, а как можно было бы изменить метод Play(), чтобы можно было закрашивать только определенные слова, а не все.

Comment: @Bulson: Ну для этого по идее придётся больше поизвращаться. Метод `Play()` тупой, он просто пользуется рассчитанными для него в методе `Create()` координатами. Нужно будет для начала поменять структуру данных: нам нужны будут границы слов, сейчас я эту информацию теряю. Затем, нужно будет положить не два `GradientStop`'а, а по три на каждое слово: один в начале, белый, другой посередине — текущая позиция разделителя, и один в конце — чёрный. (Ну или можно два в середине, как сейчас.) Ну и при анимации слова находить нужный GradientStop и двигать его.

Comment: @Bulson: То есть у нас получается такая структура данных: `class WordDescriptor { List<Rect> boundingBoxes; int GradientStopIndex; }`, и список этих `WordDescriptor`'ов по штуке на каждое слово.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, теперь понятно что и как можно изменить.

Comment: @Bulson: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Bulson: Да, и ещё `GradientStop`'ы нужно будет создавать в функции `Create`, т. к. даже их количество не известно заранее.

Comment: @VladD не как не могу разобраться с GradientStop. Есть строка с текстом ,у  меня есть функция которая по времени дает мне слова которые нужно закрашивать в тексте, Сейчас закрашивает о начала и до конца без остановки. без пауз, грубо говоря не в такт музыке)). Не могли бы вы помочь разобраться

Comment: @N1VaL: Ну это вам нужно сделать закраску по кускам. [Вот здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/632801/10105) есть пример, для которого куски совпадают со строками, но по сути можно резать на любые куски, какие вам нужно.

Comment: @VladD, Нарезка идет вот здесь ? я правильно понимаю? var boundingBoxes = // побуквенная ширина и позиции Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length) .Where(k => !char.IsWhiteSpace(text[k])) .Select(k => formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point(), k, 1) .Bounds) .ToList();

Comment: @N1VaL: Здесь идёт нарезка на отдельные буквы, с выкидыванием пробелов. А разделение на строки идёт в цикле `foreach (var rect in boundingBoxes)` в другом ответе. Если вы хотите резать на слова, вам нужно не выбрасывать пробелы. Получится что-то такое: http://pastebin.com/HXS5Tu9t

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в сторону RichTextBox. Позволяет получить часть текста TextRange и отформатировать методом ApplyPropertyValue.

Answer (score 3):

Можете исползовать [The TextBlock control - Inline formatting](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/)

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
tb.Inlines.Add("An example on ");
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("the TextBlock control ") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
tb.Inlines.Add("using ");
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("inline ") { FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic });
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("text formatting ") { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
tb.Inlines.Add("from ");
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Code-Behind") { TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline });
tb.Inlines.Add(".");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]