# Каким образом можно реализовать бегущую подсветку (выделение) многострочного текста?

Tags: c#, wpf, path

Здесь уже был вопрос про закраску текста и на него был дан  [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631051/222542).

Вкратце суть решения состоит в создании `FormattedText` из содержимого скрытого `TextBlock`, а затем создается геометрия из `FormattedText`, которая отображается с помощью `Path`, который в свою очередь закрашивается с помощью анимации на нем.

И все прекрасно работает пока текст занимает одну строку, а вот когда строк несколько, получается не то, что хотелось бы.

[image: Пример неправильного закрашивания текста]

XAML я повторять не буду, т.к. он полностью совпадает с таковым в выше указанном ответе. Мой код тоже мало чем отличается, но я его приведу для ясности вопроса.

```
private List<Rect> _RectsForFill;   // прямоугольники с каждым символом
private double _LengthFillText;      // общая ширина рисованного текста

//анимация
Storyboard _Storyboard;
DoubleAnimation _FromAnimation;
DoubleAnimation _ToAnimation;

private void CreateFillText()
{
    //получаем текстовое содержимое
    TextBlock tb = this.textBlockHidden;
    var text = tb.Text;

    //создаем экземпляр форматированного текста
    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
        text,
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(
            tb.FontFamily,
            tb.FontStyle,
            tb.FontWeight,
            tb.FontStretch),
            tb.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black // конкретная кисть нам не важна, мы используем только геометрию
        );

    //берем переносы строк у эталонного текстблока
    formattedText.MaxTextWidth = this.textBlockHidden.Width;
    formattedText.MaxTextHeight = this.textBlockHidden.Height;

    // стащили геометрию у текста...
    var geo = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point());
    // ...и отдали её Path'у
    Target.Data = geo;

    //вычислим прямоугольники для заполнения
    GetRectsForFill(text, formattedText);
}

private void GetRectsForFill(string text, FormattedText formattedText)
{
    var bb = formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point());
    _LengthFillText = bb.Bounds.Width; // общая ширина

    //заполняем коллекцию побуквенных боксов
    _RectsForFill = Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length)
                            .Select(k => formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point(), k, 1)
                                                                   .Bounds)
                        .ToList();

    //ссылки на анимацию для дальнейшей работы с ней
    _Storyboard = (Storyboard)Target.Resources["AnimationStoryboard"];
    _FromAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)_Storyboard.Children[0];
    _ToAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)_Storyboard.Children[1];
}
```

Вот метод, заполняет черным отрисованный текст

```
/// <summary>
/// Закрашивание рисованного текста
/// </summary>
/// <param name="startPos">начальная позиция слова</param>
/// <param name="count">число закрашиваемых букв в слове</param>
public void FillTextPath(int startPos, int count)
{
    if (count == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(count));

    //вычисляем индекс необходимого прямоугольника
    int index = startPos + count;
    if (index >= _RectsForFill.Count) index = _RectsForFill.Count - 1;

    //необходимый прямоугольник
    Rect box = _RectsForFill[index];

    //закрашиваем
    _FromAnimation.From = box.Left / _LengthFillText;
    _FromAnimation.To = box.Right / _LengthFillText;
    _ToAnimation.From = box.Left / _LengthFillText;
    _ToAnimation.To = box.Right / _LengthFillText;
    _Storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Сейчас подрихтую то решение для случая многострочного текста.

Comment: @VladD, очень ждемс:) Я уже думал сделать через создание отдельных `Path` для каждой необходимой строки, но пока не определился как определять, когда текст в `TextBlock` получил перенос на др. строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пошли правильным путём, разбить на отдельные `Path`'ы — хорошая идея.

Давайте её реализуем до конца.

Для начала, функциональность проигрывания уже достаточно сложна, так что вынесем её в отдельный `UserControl`. Затем, каждый контрол пусть отвечает за одну строку. Чтобы не искать куски по геометрии, просто отрежем эту строку при помощи `Clip`'а. На вход в `UserControl` будем подавать результаты разбора текста на геометрию (функцией `Create`).

```
<UserControl x:Class="KaraokeText.SingleLine"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Path Name="Target" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5">
        <Path.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" x:Name="TargetFrom"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" x:Name="TargetTo" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
        <Path.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.25"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="TargetFrom"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.25"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="TargetTo"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Path.Resources>
    </Path>
</UserControl>
```

В code-behind будет анимация:

```
public partial class SingleLine : UserControl
{
    List<Rect> boundingBoxes;
    double extent;

    public SingleLine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SingleLine(Geometry geo, List<Rect> boundingBoxes, double totalExtent) : this()
    {
        Target.Data = geo;
        extent = totalExtent;
        Rect clip = boundingBoxes.Aggregate(Rect.Union);
        Clip = new RectangleGeometry(clip);
        this.boundingBoxes = boundingBoxes;
    }

    public async Task Play()
    {
        var storyboard = (Storyboard)Target.Resources["AnimationStoryboard"];
        var fromAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)storyboard.Children[0];
        var toAnimation = (DoubleAnimation)storyboard.Children[1];

        foreach (var b in boundingBoxes)
        {
            await Task.Delay(250); // перерыв между буквами
            fromAnimation.From = b.Left / extent;
            fromAnimation.To = b.Right / extent;
            toAnimation.From = b.Left / extent;
            toAnimation.To = b.Right / extent;
            storyboard.Begin();
            await Task.Delay(250); // дождёмся конца анимации
        }
    }
}
```

Зачем нам нужна такая сложность с `Clip` и `totalExtent`? К сожалению, я не нашёл метода выкусить только нужную часть геометрии. Поэтому мы даём на вход **всю** геометрию, а хотим показывать только текущую строку. Для этого мы вычисляем прямоугольник, соответствующий нужной части геометрии (текущей строке), и отрезаем отображение остального при помощи `Clip`'а. Но наши вычисления коэффициентов (`b.Left / extent` и т. д.) требуют процента от общей ширины `Path`'а, а не ширины текущей строки! (Напомню, наш `Path` получает геометрию всей строки, включая остальные строки тоже.) Поэтому приходится передавать ещё и общую ширину.

Теперь основной код. Он стал проще, так как часть функциональности отделилась. В нём мы не можем положить один, фиксированный `Path`, так как у нас количество строк не известно заранее. Поэтому контролы будем добавлять динамически.

Главное окно выглядит просто:

```
<Window x:Class="KaraokeText.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="Container">
        <TextBlock Name="Source" FontSize="24" Visibility="Hidden" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="А-а, в Африке реки вот такой ширины &#x000d;А-а, в Африке горы вот такой вышины"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

И code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (o, args) => Create(); // вначале запустим Create
        PreviewKeyDown += (o, args) => Play(); // а по нажатию клавиши - Play
    }

    // список контролов, отображающих строки
    List<SingleLine> lineControls = new List<SingleLine>();

    void Create() // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816(v=vs.110).aspx
    {
        TextBlock tb = Source;
        var text = tb.Text;
        FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
            text,
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(
                tb.FontFamily,
                tb.FontStyle,
                tb.FontWeight,
                tb.FontStretch),
            tb.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black);

        // установили максимальную ширину, чтобы текст был разбит на части
        formattedText.MaxTextWidth = Source.ActualWidth;

        var boundingBoxes =  // побуквенная ширина и позиции
            Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length)
                      .Where(k => !char.IsWhiteSpace(text[k]))
                      .Select(k => formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point(), k, 1)
                                                .Bounds)
                      .ToList();

        // вычисляем охватывающий прямоугольник всех прямоугольников
        var totalBb = boundingBoxes.Aggregate(Rect.Union);
        var totalExtent = totalBb.Width;

        List<List<Rect>> boundingBoxesByLine = new List<List<Rect>>();
        List<Rect> currentLine = null;
        double lastRectBottom = double.NegativeInfinity;
        foreach (var rect in boundingBoxes)
        {
            // проверка на новую строку. если верх текущего прямоугольника там же,
            // где низ предыдущего прямоугольника, или ещё ниже - новая строка, иначе нет
            if (rect.Top >= lastRectBottom)
            {
                // добавим старую строку в список строк
                if (currentLine != null)
                    boundingBoxesByLine.Add(currentLine);
                // новый пустой контейнер прямоугольников для новой строки
                currentLine = new List<Rect>();
            }
            currentLine.Add(rect);
            lastRectBottom = rect.Bottom;
        }
        if (currentLine != null) // последнюю строку не теряем
            boundingBoxesByLine.Add(currentLine);

        // стащили геометрию у текста...
        var geo = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point());

        // строим по контролу для каждой строки:
        foreach (var line in boundingBoxesByLine)
        {
            // ... отдавая ему геометрию:
            var lineControl = new SingleLine(geo, line, totalExtent);
            Container.Children.Add(lineControl);
            lineControls.Add(lineControl);
        }
    }

    async void Play()
    {
        // проигрываем просто построчно
        foreach (var line in lineControls)
            await line.Play();
    }
}
```

Всё!

---

Результат:

[image: простая анимашка по имени Наташка]

Comment: Спасибо, это нужно переспать:) Завтра утром попробую повторить.

Comment: @Bulson: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, всё срастётся.

Comment: Для меня остался загадкой алгоритм разделения на строки начиная со строки `var totalBb = boundingBoxes.Aggregate(Rect.Union);` и заканчивая `if (currentLine != null)`. Я правильно понимаю, что вы сначала вычисляете общую ширину объединенных прямоугольников, полученных из букв? Но ведь выше были выброшены пробельные прямоугольники, значит общая полученная ширина будет меньше реальной? Да, и в цикле принцип разделения по `Top` и `Bottom` для меня совсем не понятная вещь. Вы могли бы в ответ добавить поясняющие комментарии в код. Еще раз огромное спасибо.

Comment: И еще не понятно, в конструктор `SingleLine(geo, line, totalExtent)` мы передаем как общую ширину `totalExtent`, хотя это не ширина конкретной этой строки, а общая ширина всех строк, как так?

Comment: Извините, и еще вот в конструкторе `SingleLine` вот эта строка `Clip = new RectangleGeometry(clip);` целая головоломка. Зачем нужна эта обрезка по контуру? Спасибо, если поможете понять :)

Comment: @Bulson: Сейчас допишу, момент.

Comment: @Bulson: `Rect.Union` вычисляет не суммарную ширину, а охватывающий прямоугольник. Как-то так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9tsA.png

Comment: @Bulson: Дописал ещё пояснение в ответ.

Comment: Теперь стало гораздо понятнее, что делается. Спасибо за пояснения.